# Может ли старый вопрос считаться дубликатом более нового?

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты

Хотелось бы прояснить политику сайта относительно следующей ситуации:

Имеется старый вопрос (N-годичной давности) с принятым ответом. Тут появляется новый более общий вопрос, но ответ на который в том числе покрывает ситуацию и со старым вопросом.

Имеет ли смысл помечать такой старый вопрос как "дубликат" более нового? С одной стороны это нелогично, с другой - сайт позволяет это сделать (т.е. не проверяет даты вопросов, когда выставляешь тревогу "закрыть как дубликат").

А если старый вопрос не имеет принятого ответа, подход тот же?

Comment: если старый вопрос более узкий и имеет соответственно более специфичный (легче для использования) ответ, то новый вопрос не следует рассматривать как дубликат, даже если какая-то часть ответа  на новый вопрос может помочь в решении старой проблемы.

Comment: Уважаемаые модераторы. Почему закрывается популярный, вопрос. А на проблему не обращют внимание? Вопросы на мете закрываются без объясенения

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Да.

Практика побеждает логику. Если новый вопрос сформулирован более внятно, а ответы подробнее, то и модератору проще, и пользователям удобнее, если основным станет новый вопрос. Если ценные ответы есть и там, и там, то модераторы могут перенести ответ, вроде, правда тогда могут возникнуть проблемы с неточным соответствием между вопросами.

С точки зрения движка требуется, чтобы у цели закрытия как дубликата был принятый или заплюсованный ответ.

Comment: Перенести ответ можно с помощью объединения вопросов - тогда переносятся все ответы и все комментарии к вопросу. Обычно это применяется только к идентичным вопросам.

Comment: А почему у закрываемого вопроса должен быть принятый или заплюсованный ответ?

Comment: @alexolut Чтобы не разочаровать того, чей вопрос закрыли.

Comment: @Squidward это только в ситуациях, когда дубликатом признается более старый или во всех?

Comment: @alexolut Всегда. Это требование на уровне движка.

Comment: @Squidward Разве? Новый вопрос может быть закрыт как дубликат и без наличия у него принятых или заплюсованных ответов. Но надо автору вопроса согласиться с тем, что ответ на его вопрос уже существует (с моим вопросом на enSO так было). Может быть и без участия автора можно, не уверен.

Comment: @alexolut Может, изменили, я не в курсе. Но раньше так было.

Comment: *А почему у закрываемого вопроса должен быть принятый или заплюсованный ответ?* — не должен быть. Discord он же Squidward плохо сформулировал ответ и не понял вашего комментария. принятый или заплюсованный ответ должен быть у того вопроса из «дублирующейся» пары, который остаётся открытым. кстати, и этого даже не требуется, если оба вопроса заданы одним и тем же автором.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Участнику Squidward, также известному как Discord, также известному как Athari, также известному как Прохоров А. Д., также известному под десятком других имён, интересно было бы узнать, есть ли нормальная замена на человеческом языке громоздким, труднопроизносимым и трудновоспринимаемым конструкциям "вопрос, использующийся в качестве цели закрытия вопроса как дубликата" или "вопрос из дублирующейся пары, остающийся открытым". Также он благодарен за пояснение технических требований движка, потому что сам начал сомневаться в их наличии в силу наблюдаемых на сайте закрытий.

Comment: Кстати, движок позволяет выбрать в качестве цели или вопрос с заплюсованным ответом, или вопрос без ответа вообще. А вот на вопрос с ответом, но не заплюсованным - срабатывает валидатор.

Comment: Уважаемаые модераторы. Почему закрывается популярный, вопрос. А на проблему не обращют внимание? Вопросы на мете закрываются без объясенения