# Закрытие дубликатов со ссылками на свои ответы

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, дубликаты

Интересно следующее. Имеет ли место быть то, что существенная часть вопросов, закрывающихся как дубликаты, имеют ссылки на вопросы, в которых ответ дан кем-либо из закрывающих?

То есть интересно, в какой мере желание закрыть вопрос продиктовано желанием сослаться косвенно на свой ответ. Всегда ли эти ответы единственно верные или опубликованы первыми? Или отслеживать дубликаты особенно не интересно, если приходится сопоставлять вопросы с чужими ответами? Не искривляется ли в некотором смысле объективность на ruSO в этом вопросе?

Comment: первый принцип на сайте: "assume good faith" -- то есть, если нет явного доказательства обратного, стоит предполагать добрые намерения. "Единственно верным" крайне мало что бывает в этой жизни и срок публикации не так важен как качество ответа для соответствующего вопроса.

Answer (score 16):

Если дубликат по метке, которой интересуется закрывающий, то вполне логично, что он закроет дублем своим, ведь он про него помнит. Я тут каких-то задних мыслей не вижу. Просто на SO поисковой движок по вопросам довольно <strike>вср</strike> кривой.

> То есть интересно в какой мере желание закрыть вопрос продиктовано
>   желанием сослаться косвенно на свой ответ

Ну а какая разница, ведь там ещё 4 голоса нужно. Исключение, разве что, модераторы (но за ними такого не замечал) и тысячники по метке вроде Грунди и Ипатьева. Но подразумевается, что пользователи с таких вкладом вроде как считаются надёжными.

> Всегда ли эти ответы единственно верные или опубликованны первыми?

Не принципиально, если они отвечают на вопрос. Но, насколько помню, в каком-то обсуждении на мете пришли к решению, что желательно выбирать более ранний ответ.

Ещё по теме:

- [Что делать с вопросами-дубликатами?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5218/15479)
- [Может ли старый вопрос считаться дубликатом более нового?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3312/15479)

> Не искривляется ли в некотором смысле объективность на ruSO в этом
>   вопросе?

Объективности нет в вопросах, где решение принимает человек. Именно поэтому для закрытия нужно 5 голосов.

Comment: постоянно закрываю своими, кроме `[faq]`, их найти проще :)

Comment: Справедливости ради, человек с золотой медалькой за тег может вопросы как  дубликаты в одиночку без всякого голосования

Comment: @Viktorov я их и имел ввиду, когда писал "тысячники" (:

Comment: @Suvitruf мои извинения. Я как то умудрился вообще не заметить фразу про тысячников вообще.