# Смена направления дубликата для вопроса

Tags: поддержка, дубликаты

Хотел бы попросить модераторов сменить направление дубликата для вопроса [Разница (отличия) между PUT и PATCH в REST](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1070324/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-put-%d0%b8-patch-%d0%b2-rest?noredirect=1#comment2365832_1070324)

Comment: А почему вы решили, что должно быть закрыто в обратную сторону?

Comment: @АндрейNOP https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3312/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be

Comment: И? Не понял намека, никаких правил с датами вопросов нет, можно дубликатить в любую сторону

Comment: Ладно, собственно. Как скажете. Мне немного надоело спорить. Но такие штуки демотивируют.